# ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have created an alert dialog with custom layout, it is working fine but when I try to set the single choice item to alertDialogBuilder it gives `ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams` error

```
    View viewDialog = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_verify, null,false);

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(viewDialog);

    final TextView tvDialogTitle = (TextView) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_textview_title);

    final Button btnCancel = (Button) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_cancel);
    final Button btnVerify = (Button) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_verify);
    btnCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnVerify.setText("cancel");
    btnVerify.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
    btnVerify.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_white);


    //set single layout structure
    alertDialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(arrayReportType, selectedIndex, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            selectedIndex=which;
            tvReportStatus.setText(arrayReportType[selectedIndex]);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    Typeface font_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), Constants.FONT_BOLD);
    tvDialogTitle.setTypeface(font_bold);
    tvDialogTitle.setText("Summary");
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

UPDATE: XML FILE from which I'm inflating the alert Dialog

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_textview_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialog_ll_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button

            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_white"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_verify"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_blue"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

import related to question

```
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Comment: Clean-Rebuild First .show your xml and import code

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have added the `xml` file and rebuilding didn't help

Comment: okay .please share import code

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya updated

Comment: `import android.widget.LinearLayout` instead of `v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;`

Comment: I think this crash is related to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231238

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)**

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an instance .

**Don't**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

**DO**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
```

**NOTE**

You are cally **`support.v7`** library .**Call Native Library** .

Comment: I changed `import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` to `import android.app.AlertDialog` solved my problem, i'm accepting your answer for calling native library

Comment: @rookieDeveloper I guess the problem .

Comment: But there is a reason for using the support version! I got exactly the same problem - my code worked and the problem came with a newer version of the support library!

Comment: @IntelliJ Amira That's why this is not a solution at all! The problem was introduced with v25 of the support library, it was not there in v24! And somebody using the support AlertDialog does this for a reason and not for fun. Thus, I cannot see how this is a valid solution... sorry!

Answer (score 3):

@Zordid is correct.  This is a bug in AOSP when using Support Library 25.  Try using another version of the support library or wait for the fix.  There are workarounds posted in the AOSP issue as well.

[Link to AOSP issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231238&q=AlertDialog%20v7&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new support library version 25.4.0 which fixes this issue.

As this library has just been released, make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com", e.g.

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com"
       }
    }
```

}